# Import single columns from txt file in Python avoiding headers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new in Python and please apologize me for my beginner question.
I have a txt file, like in the figure and I would like to import three columns (1st 2nd 6th) and store the data in three different vectors avoiding the all the headers.

I know that there are similar questions, but I did not manage :(

Cheeeers

```
Name: Z1836_Tb10-TbCoTb_DL_MzDown_FS_Phi-90∞_I-665uA_Offs-0uA_Avg-5s_(0)_S1.dat
Date: Samstag, 1. Juni 2019 - new scaling
Scan Type: Field Scan
Angle [∞]: 90
Current [uA]: 665
Frequency [Hz]: 10
Offset [uA]: 0
Sampling Rate [Hz]: 204800
Averaging Duration [s]: 5
Measurement Duration: 00:30:44
----------
Field   R\+(1f) Real    R\+(1f) Img R\+(1f) Mag R\+(1f) Phase   R\+(2f) Real    R\+(2f) Img R\+(2f) Mag R\+(2f) Phase   Field Set
mT  \g(W)   \g(W)   \g(W)   ∞   \g(W)   \g(W)   \g(W)   ∞   A
1019.14 -0.135007229    0.015354704 -0.135877588    173.51149082    -2.776103401E-6 -2.996982259E-6 -4.085174752E-6 -132.808926217     20
1000.95 -0.134959525    0.015398131 -0.135835105    173.491016631   -1.41565391E-5  4.583223348E-6  -1.487997096E-5 162.060479267    19.6
982.67  -0.134951253    0.015396305 -0.13582668 173.491386228   1.196964996E-5  -3.522605161E-6 1.247722995E-5  -16.398879321    19.2
964.17  -0.134935857    0.015381909 -0.135809751    173.496684402   5.150366012E-7  -2.854084284E-5 2.854548953E-5  -88.966175556    18.8
945.27  -0.134941957    0.015372557 -0.135814754    173.500895888   -7.177408364E-6 -2.703168168E-5 -2.796832146E-5 -104.869975658   18.4
926.12  -0.134916606    0.01535581  -0.13578767 173.506706039   -1.599523307E-5 1.704176103E-5  -2.337240039E-5 133.18562213       18
906.81  -0.134895719    0.015356654 -0.135767013    173.505355181   -7.367897986E-6 2.807593732E-6  -7.884700584E-6 159.14027614     17.6
887.36  -0.134877099    0.015409203 -0.135754468    173.482430298   -1.011942317E-5 -1.588290362E-5 -1.883266717E-5 -122.502303207   17.2
```

[txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEieD.png)

Comment: Can you please copy&paste the file into your question or post it on pastebin so moderators can edit your question?

Comment: Do what Jan said and though you "did not manage" it's better if we see your attempt at doing the work. Perhaps your attempt just needs some tweaking.

Comment: Do you have to use Python to extract the data from a .txt file? If not you could try importing this .txt file in an excel. Excel in fact has a function to turn txt into a spreadsheet. And that txt file is nicely formatted, so excel may be able to well recognize your columns

Answer (score 2):

Sample Data:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
Cum repudiandae ipsam repellendus quas facere quidem 
sit saepe libero ut pariatur consectetur ad at nisi consequatur,
minima cupiditate iusto? Aut, quibusdam. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla consequuntur hic tempora nobis libero nihil maxime magnam ratione voluptatum veritatis ipsum ducimus enim, sequi beatae suscipit laboriosam maiores mollitia soluta.

col1 col2 col3 col4
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4   
1 2 3 4  
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

#Set you skiprows according to your text file
df = pd.read_csv('sample.txt', delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=5)

vector_col_2 = list(df.iloc[:,1])
vector_col_4 = list(df.iloc[:,3])
print('V2: ',vector_col_2)
print('V4: ',vector_col_4)
```

Output:

```
V2:  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
V4:  [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented an example script for you. The code contains comments in related parts.

**Code:**

```
# Open the related file.
with open("ci/common/python_utils/test_text.txt", "r") as opened_file:
    # Read the all lines of file. It returns a list type object.
    lines = opened_file.readlines()
    # Cut the unrelated lines (the header).
    related_content = lines[13:]
    # Init the vectors (lists).
    col1, col2, col6 = [], [], []
    for row in related_content:
        # You should use the expected column -1 for the list indexing.
        col1.append(row.split()[0])
        col2.append(row.split()[1])
        col6.append(row.split()[5])

# Print the content of columns
print("First column content: {}".format(col1))
print("Second column content: {}".format(col2))
print("Sixth column content: {}".format(col6))
```

**Used txt file:**

```
Name: Z1836_Tb10-TbCoTb_DL_MzDown_FS_Phi-90∞_I-665uA_Offs-0uA_Avg-5s_(0)_S1.dat
Date: Samstag, 1. Juni 2019 - new scaling
Scan Type: Field Scan
Angle [∞]: 90
Current [uA]: 665
Frequency [Hz]: 10
Offset [uA]: 0
Sampling Rate [Hz]: 204800
Averaging Duration [s]: 5
Measurement Duration: 00:30:44
----------
Field   R\+(1f) Real    R\+(1f) Img R\+(1f) Mag R\+(1f) Phase   R\+(2f) Real    R\+(2f) Img R\+(2f) Mag R\+(2f) Phase   Field Set
mT  \g(W)   \g(W)   \g(W)   ∞   \g(W)   \g(W)   \g(W)   ∞   A
1019.14 -0.135007229    0.015354704 -0.135877588    173.51149082    -2.776103401E-6 -2.996982259E-6 -4.085174752E-6 -132.808926217     20
1000.95 -0.134959525    0.015398131 -0.135835105    173.491016631   -1.41565391E-5  4.583223348E-6  -1.487997096E-5 162.060479267    19.6
982.67  -0.134951253    0.015396305 -0.13582668 173.491386228   1.196964996E-5  -3.522605161E-6 1.247722995E-5  -16.398879321    19.2
964.17  -0.134935857    0.015381909 -0.135809751    173.496684402   5.150366012E-7  -2.854084284E-5 2.854548953E-5  -88.966175556    18.8
945.27  -0.134941957    0.015372557 -0.135814754    173.500895888   -7.177408364E-6 -2.703168168E-5 -2.796832146E-5 -104.869975658   18.4
926.12  -0.134916606    0.01535581  -0.13578767 173.506706039   -1.599523307E-5 1.704176103E-5  -2.337240039E-5 133.18562213       18
906.81  -0.134895719    0.015356654 -0.135767013    173.505355181   -7.367897986E-6 2.807593732E-6  -7.884700584E-6 159.14027614     17.6
887.36  -0.134877099    0.015409203 -0.135754468    173.482430298   -1.011942317E-5 -1.
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python ci/common/python_utils/test_file.py 
First column content: ['1019.14', '1000.95', '982.67', '964.17', '945.27', '926.12', '906.81', '887.36']
Second column content: ['-0.135007229', '-0.134959525', '-0.134951253', '-0.134935857', '-0.134941957', '-0.134916606', '-0.134895719', '-0.134877099']
Sixth column content: ['-2.776103401E-6', '-1.41565391E-5', '1.196964996E-5', '5.150366012E-7', '-7.177408364E-6', '-1.599523307E-5', '-7.367897986E-6', '-1.011942317E-5']
```

Comment: I got this error at line: lines = opened_file.readlines()
 UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-97bdb83f1a38> in <module>

Comment: I have tried your text file with `Python2` as well as `Python3` an I didn't got Error. But, If you use `Python3 ` you can change the context manager like this: `with open('text.txt', 'r', errors='replace') as opened_file: ...` or you should try to force the encoding in context manager like this `with open('text.txt', encoding='utf-8') as opened_fie: ...` FYI: You can set the default encoding in the first line with `#! -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: thank you for your help and your code works!. Anyway I would need to store columns into numerical vectors, instead of rows. This is what puzzles me.

Comment: Ohhh.... Sorry, I see. It was my fault, I have should paid more attentions to your question. I have updated my answer and now it calculates the related columns of your text file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
import re

with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

data = []

for line in lines:
    if not re.search(r'[A-DF-Za-df-z]', line): #Don't allow any letter except E or e
        if re.search(r'\d', line): # It has at least to have a line with a number
            data.append(line.replace("\n","").split())

data = list(zip(*data))

print(data[0])
print(data[1])
print(data[5])
```

## Output:

```
('1019.14', '1000.95', '982.67', '964.17', '945.27', '926.12', '906.81', '887.36')
('-0.135007229', '-0.134959525', '-0.134951253', '-0.134935857', '-0.134941957', '-0.134916606', '-0.134895719', '-0.134877099')
('-2.776103401E-6', '-1.41565391E-5', '1.196964996E-5', '5.150366012E-7', '-7.177408364E-6', '-1.599523307E-5', '-7.367897986E-6', '-1.011942317E-5')
```

## How it works:

We will go first line by line. If the line contains any letter not equal `E/e` we will skip that line. That is to ignore the header.  (E is allowed because of scientific notation)

Then if the line doesn't contain any number we skip that line as well. (This is in case of empty lines or in your file the line: `-------`.

If the line doesn't have any letter besides E and at least have a number we put it into `data` splitted.

After that we use zip to format it in columns and then you can print the columns you are looking for.

## Constraints

1. This approach won't work if any columns have text into it. It works in your case because you have only number.
2. If a line in the header has no letters except `E` and at least a number it will fail as well.
3. This is a flexible approach therefore you don't need pre knowledge of the file about the number of lines the header has. But you have to know the 1. and 2. constraint. In case you can't guarantee the 1. and 2. constraint you can achieve the same with skippling lines. Change the `for-loop` like this:

```
#This might change according to your need, in your example it's 13.
skip_lines = 13

for line in lines[skip_lines:]:
    data.append(line.replace("\n","").split())
```